# How to create Java cloud applicaiton to block websites in client side

Tags: java, node.js, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to develop cloud application to block websites based on users and their roles.

"I want to read browser URL" it may be from Chrome, firefox etc and want to send to cloud server for user based access if user has access request will be proceed
else it will block and redirect to another page.

My Doubt is

1.) How to listen and read browser URLs without a proxy server?
2.) Is proxy server is a must for my requirement?
3.) When a user has access how response HTML page.

Comment: From your description, it seems that what you are trying to do is exactly what a proxy does. Problem is that a proxy can't filter HTTPS traffic because the URL is encrypted. Unless you have a specific scenario, I see no hope for you.